# Spring MVC + Hibernate one to one mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to develop an application using spring mvc and hibernate.
I have following entity classes

1. `Employee`
2. `EmployeePeronellDetails`
3. `EmployeeSallaryDetails`
4. `EmployeeProfesionalDetails`

I have an integer `employeeID` as a `primary key` in `employee` table which further acts as foreign key in other three tables

I have created 4 different forms to fill information to above tables.

4 forms opened one after the other

> How my entity classes should look like?

I followed few tutorials they suggested to create `Employee` class object in other classes.
So after successfully inserting data in employee table. Do I need to save respective `Employee` object in `session`? 
After this while creating `EmployeePeronellDetails` bean pass that `session's employee` object to `EmployeePeronellDetails's` setter method/constructor.

Below are my employee and EmployeePeronellDetails classes

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    private int empid;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private String lastName;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private boolean isAdmin;

    @Column
    private boolean isActive;

    @Column
    private boolean isLocked;

//geter setters
```

========================PersonalDetails class===========================

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PersonalDetails")
public class PersonalDetails {
    @Column
    @Id
    private int empId;
    @Column
    private String personalEmail;
    @Column
    private String mob;
    @Column
    private String permenantAdress;
    @Column
    private String currentAddress;
    @Column
    private String gender;
    @Column
    private String maritialStatus;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="empid")
    private Employee employee;
```

Now when I tried to call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(personalDetails);`

It gives

> org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported]

Exception.

Comment: Post your code so we can help.